# How to listen for Windows broadcast messages in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, broadcast

i have an `Object` (i.e. not a form) that wants to listen for broadcast messages from Windows, e.g.:

- [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`WM_THEMECHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What is the mechanism in .NET to setup a non-WinForm's window, that can listen for broadcast messages?

i.e. Is there a `WindowsListener` class?

### Bonus Chatter

In the olden days, in other development environments, the framework provided an [`AllocateHwnd`](http://function%20AllocateHWnd%28AMethod%3a%20TWndMethod%29%3a%20HWND;) function:

```
HWND listener = AllocateHWnd(ListenerWindowProc);
```

where `ListenerWindowProc` was my *window procedure* method:

```
private void ListenerWindowProc(ref Message msg)
{
    switch (msg.msg)
    {
       case WM_SETTINGCHANGE: 
       {
          ...
       }
       break;
       case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
       {
          ...
       }
       break;
       case WM_THEMECHANGED: 
       {
          ...
       }
       break;
       ...
   }
   DefWindowProc(msg);
}
```

The secret sauce was the `AllocateHwnd` function:

**Pseudo-code:**

```
public static HWND AllocateHWnd(WndMethod method)
{
   HWND result;
   WNDCLASS tempClass;
   Boolean classRegistered;

   UtilWindowClass.hInstance := HInstance;
   Boolean classRegistered = GetClassInfo(HInstance, UtilWindowClass.lpszClassName, tempClass);
   if (!classRegistered || (tempClass.lpfnWndProc != @DefWindowProc)
   {
      if classRegistered
      {
         UnregisterClass(utilWindowClass.lpszClassName, HInstance);
         RegisterClass(utilWindowClass);
      }
      result = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, UtilWindowClass.lpszClassName,
            '', WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, null);
      if (!Method != null)
         SetWindowLong(result, GWL_WNDPROC, UInt32(MakeObjectInstance(Method)));
   }
}
```

With a whole lot more secret code associated with `UtilWindowClass`.

And when you were done you would [DeallocateHwnd](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_DeallocateHWnd.html):

```
DeallocateHwnd(listenerWindow);
```

i know somewhere deep in the .NET framework they are going to respond to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and update internal .NET data structures. i would steal that code, but Reflector finds no reference to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`; presumably because the decompiled code doesn't show the *constant name*, just the constant **0x001A**.

**Update**:

**Note**: This object should be self-contained. Anyone using the class should not have to modify their application in order for my class to return correct data. It should listen to broadcasts from Windows itself, and not require a developer to modify their application to listen for certain messages for me (i.e. it should not break encapsulation of the difficult or complication operation)

For example:

```
public class FrobbingGrobber: IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

    public FrobbingGrobber
    {
       _hwnd = AllocateHwnd(listenerWindowProc);
    }

    protected virtual void listenerWindowProc(ref Message msg)
    {
       switch (msg.msg)
       {
          case WM_DwmColorizationColorChanged, WM_DwmCompositionChanged: 
          {
              UpdateColorizationColor();
          }
          break;
       }
       DefWindowProc(msg);
    }

    public void UpdateColorizationColor()
    {
        NativeMethods.DwmGetColorizationColorParameters_UndocumentedExport137(ref _color);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected void Dispose(Boolean safeToDisposeManagedObjects)
    {
       if (_hwnd != 0)
       {
          DeallocateHwnd(_hwnd);      
          _hwnd = 0;
       }

       if (safeToDisposeManagedObjects)
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public ~FrobbingGrobber
    {
       //If the user forgot to call Dispose i could (correctly) leak a handle, 
       //or i could fix their mistake for them
       Dispose(false);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, your AllocateHwnd function's just creating a hidden window. You can do the same in .NET, by using a small amount of Winforms. Oh, and you'll need a message loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that the examples you gave were merely that: examples. Because a number of those have managed equivalents that already wrap all of this for you. Like `WM_POWERBROADCAST` is wrapped by the [`Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx). And `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` is equivalent to [`Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

Anyway, broadcasted messages like those you describe are sent to all top-level windows, so all you really need to do is create a top-level window and override its `WndProc` method to process the notification messages that you're interested in.

Use the [`NativeWindow` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) to make things easy on yourself. In this case, you don't need everything that is provided by the `Form` class, all you need is something to wrap `CreateWindowEx` and provide a window procedure. Just create the window without the `WS_VISIBLE` flag because you don't want it appearing on the screen.

The .NET Framework does this all over the place internally. For example, the internal `TimerNativeWindow` class used for `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. If you want to check out the implementation for yourself in Reflector, start looking there. You should be able to search for constants, but drilling down into a hierarchy of classes for which you know there must be such a notification message handled internally is generally a smarter way to search. The `SystemEvents` class (discussed above) is also a good place to start looking for implementation strategies.

Do note that you can't use a message-only window here (`HWND_MESSAGE`) because [they won't receive broadcast events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only). The `TimerNativeWindow` that I mentioned above *does* do that, because it doesn't care about broadcast events, so don't just copy and paste the code from there!

Comment: The example broadcasts *were* just examples; i didn't want someone to avoid answering the question. Thank you for pointing out the classes in .NET that *do* respond do the events that .NET *does* respond to. i can see `SystemEvents` uses its own `CreateBroadcastWindow` method. In my case it looks like `NativeWindow` is the best choice; the sample on msdn even calls it `MyNativeWindowListener`.