# Is there a Windows event that gets fired when an environment variable changes?

Tags: windows, events, event-handling, environment-variables

Is there a Windows event that gets fired when an environment variable value is updated? If so, what's its event ID?

**Edit:**

The use case is I have an application that receives a copy of the current value for an environment variable when it starts up, and I'd like for it to be able to listen for an event to alert it to the fact that this environment variable may have a new value. I'm wondering if there is such an event.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to tell which environment variable has been updated from the event information, but even an event that tells my application that an environment variable has been updated would be useful.

Comment: If you mean an entry in the event log, this is very unlikely.  But I guess you could configure the permissions on the relevant registry key to enable auditing.  Auditing also has to be turned on globally, via group policy I think.  If you just mean "some way for my program to tell that the environment has changed" look up WM_SETTINGCHANGE.  (There are situations in which this will not work, e.g., if the environment is changed by a user in a different session to yours.)

Comment: The use case is I have an application that receives a copy of the current value for an environment variable when it starts up, and I'd like for it to be able to listen for an event to alert it to the fact that this environment variable may have a new value. I'm wondering if there is such an event. (Although if all such events show up in the event log, than I suppose not?)

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by "event".  The word has different meanings in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Listening for the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) message is the standard way to tell when an environment variable has been changed:

> To effect a change in the environment variables for the system or the user, broadcast this message with lParam set to the string "Environment".

For example, that's how Explorer knows when an environment variable has been changed.  It doesn't check for new or changed variables every time an application is launched, only when it sees a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.

If you happen to be using .NET, then [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332988/886887) the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message will be converted into a [SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

Comment: I'm having trouble confirming this works. I created a handler:

    private void EnvironmentSettingsChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

And tried to assign it:

    void Main()
    {
     Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += new Microsoft.Win32.UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(EnvironmentSettingsChanged);
        ...
    }

But I can't seem to hit the break point I put in my handler when I change an environment variable.

Comment: That should probably be posted as a separate question, including a [mcve].  But before that: how are you changing the environment variable?

Comment: I'm changing it through the windows Environment Variable dialog.

Comment: OK, so that should have worked.  I'm not familiar enough with .NET to comment on your code fragment, if you post a new question tagged .net and c# it should get to the attention of the right people.  Make sure it includes a [mcve], not just a few lines of code.

Comment: ... and do make sure the [question and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9330517/886887) don't already address your problem.